# Live search without JQuery in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a  js file that looks as shown:

```
var tracks = [
    {
        title:"Dunnock",
        mp3:"Birdsong-Dunnock.mp3",
        lyrics:"The Dunnock or hedge sparrow has a fast warbling song often delivered from the top of a hedge or bush"
    },
    {
        title:"Robin",
        mp3 :"Birdsong-Robin.mp3",
        lyrics :"Unusually among British birds, both the male and the female robins sing"
    }
]
```

I start my javascript with the following. music.js is in the same folder as the html document.

```
<script src="music.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

My search function looks like shown. It loads the results into a select box

```
function searchIt(str) {
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '';
  for (var i in albums) {
    for (var j in albums[i].tracks) {
      if(albums[i].tracks[j].lyrics.toLowerCase().indexOf(str)  >= 0) { 
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerText = albums[i].tracks[j].title;
        document.getElementById("results").appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works but only if I call the function with the user's search input after's he's typed it. I need to find a way to make this live search but I don't really know where to start. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: How is the `searchIt` function being called? Do you bind it to a `onchange` event? You can try to bind the function to `onkeyup` event.

Comment: I haven't called it yet purposefuly. To test the function, i made a button "search" which calls the function, but it is supposed to be doing a live search.

Comment: EDIT: I looked up the onkeyup event, it wouldn't work in my code as I've had to implement and use a virtual keyboard.

Comment: If you are using virtual keyboard then you can go with onmouseup event.

Comment: I ended up calling the search function everytime I process a key from the virtual keyboard.